# building a 2D array in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to build an array for a school project, scenario is this:

You have a city that is 30 miles (y) by 20 miles (x) with roads every mile, have to write code that gives the best location for placement of a distribution center based on the business locations and cost to delivery goods to each.

I have one bit of code that records the number of client businesses, an array that records the locations of the businesses, and an array that stores volume of product each client buys.

Where I'm stuck at, is I think I should build an array that is 0 to 30, 0 to 20 (the size of the city) but I have to evaluate the cost based on user defined precision (.25, .5, 1, and 2 miles) so I should have the array be able to store the values from the calculations for 120 by 80 cells.

Not sure if that makes sense, here is the requirements:
Specifically, your program should be able to complete the following tasks:

1. Read the customer data, and user input for analysis resolution. Your program must be designed to
   accommodate changes in the number of customers, their locations, and their product delivery volumes. User options for analysis resolution will be: 0.25 miles, 0.5 miles, 1 mile, and 2 miles.
2. Validate that user input is numeric and valid.
3. Analyze the costs at all possible distribution center locations (which may be collocated with customer
   locations), and determine the optimums.
4. Display the X and Y values of the optimum distribution center locations and the corresponding minimum
   weekly cost. There may be multiple locations with the same minimum cost.
5. Display the costs at all locations adjacent to the optimums, in order to show the sensitivity of the result.

The formulas to use are:

Distance to customer `(Di)=abs|x-xi|+|y+yi|`

Cost for customer `(Ci)=1/2*Di*Vi` (volume of customer product)* Ft

```
Ft = 0.03162*y+0.04213*x+0.4462

cost = sum Ci from 1 to number of clients
```

Below is my code so far, I started it to have it basically build the array and display it on a second sheet, so I can visualize it but I can't have that in the final product. In debugging it, it gets to the line of code `di =` and gives me a subscript out of range.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub load()
Dim Cust!, x#, y#, volume#(), n!, loc#(), i%, vol#, xi#, ci#, di#, j#
Dim choices#, val#(), nptsx!, nptsy!, Ft#, lowx!, lowy!, low!, M!
Dim costmatrix#(), npts!, cost!()

'find number of customers
Cust = 0
Do While Cells(8 + Cust, 1).Value <> ""
  Cust = Cust + 1
Loop

If Cust < 2 Then
  MsgBox "number of customers must be greater than 1."
  Exit Sub
End If

'establist array of customer locations
ReDim loc#(1, Cust)
  For j = 1 To Cust
    x = Cells(7 + j, 2)
    y = Cells(7 + j, 3)
  Next j

ReDim volume#(Cust, 1)
  For i = 1 To Cust
    vol = Cells(7 + i, 4)
  Next i

choices = Cells(3, 7).Value
nptsx = 30 / choices + 1
nptsy = 20 / choices + 1

 '30x20 grid
ReDim costmatrix(x To nptsx, y To nptsy)
  For x = 0 To nptsx - 1
    Sheet3.Cells(1, x + 2) = x * choices
  Next x
  For y = 0 To nptsy - 1
    Sheet3.Cells(2 + y, 1) = y * choices
  Next y


  For x = 0 To nptsx - 1
  For y = 0 To nptsy - 1
    For k = 1 To Cust
  di = Abs(x * choices - Sheet1.Cells(7 + j, 2)) + Abs(y * choices - Sheet1.Cells(7 + j, 3))
      Ft = 0.03162 * Sheet1.Cells(7 + j, 3) + 0.4213 * Sheet1.Cells(7 + j, 2) + 0.4462



ci = 1 / 2 * di * vol * Ft
  Sheet3.Cells(x + 2, 2 + y) = ci
  Next k

  Next y
  Next x

lowx = x
lowy = y

Range("I9:J:3").Clear

Range("I9") = "optimum"
Range("J9") = lowx * choices
Range("K9") = lowy * choices
Range("L9") = low

i = 9
If lowy < npts - 1 Then
    i = i + 1
    Cells(1, "I") = "Increment North"
    Cells(1, "L") = cost(lowx, lowy + 1)
End If
If lowy > 0 Then
    i = i + 1
    Cells(1, "I") = "Increment South"
    Cells(1, "L") = cost(lowx, lowy - 1)
End If
If lowx < npts - 1 Then
    i = i + 1
    Cells(1, "I") = "Increment East"
    Cells(1, "L") = cost(lowx, lowy + 1)
End If
If lowx > 0 Then
i = i + 1
    Cells(1, "I") = "Increment West"
    Cells(1, "L") = cost(lowx, lowy - 1)
End If

End Sub
```

Updated, I have built the array, but I need to figure out how to do the calculations for all clients in one cell at a time, adding the results for each client together and putting the sum of them into the cell, then going onto the next cell.

Answer (score 0):

When you dimension `loc#` via

```
ReDim loc#(Cust, 2)
```

The first index must be between 1 and `Cust`

The you have the loop

```
For k = 1 To Cust
x = Cells(7 + k, 2)
y = Cells(7 + k, 3)
Next k
```

After this loop runs `k` has value `Cust + 1`, not `Cust` since for-loops in VBA first increment the counter and then test if it has exceeded the limit.

You don't use `k` again until the line

```
di = Abs(Sheet3.Cells(1, x + 2) - loc(k, 1))
```

At this stage `k` is `Cust + 1` -- which is one more than the highest permissible subscript, hence the subscript out of range error.

In context, I think that you meant to use `j` rather than `k` in both that line and the next line. I don't know if your code has other issues, but getting rid of `k` in those lines should help.

Comment: Thank you, I made those changes and I've made some progress.  What I have now is on sheet3 I get values to populate however where it lists 30 positions across the top, it will only input results in for the first 20, and same going down the horizontal, it lists 20 but then gives results for 30.

Plus all the results for each row is identical, so it's 0s all across the top, then 1.09319 next row down, and so on and so forth.

It seems to want to keep going and it gives me a subscript out of range again after displaying all that info.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track so far, what I'm stuck at now it, my formulas are going through for the first client and populating the data into the array, but when it tries to go to the second client it crashes.

How do I get it so that the array will run through all the calculations for the first client, store that info, calculate everything for the second client, add the two amounts together, store that, start the third client and so on and so forth until the end?